# What's the equivalent of hg pull and merge in git

Tags: git, merge, mercurial

Coming from mercurial, I'm struggling a bit with the terminology and methods for git.  Here's the current situation:

Both servers share the same repository.

- On Server 1 a developer committed a change to file.php.
- On Server 2 a developer committed a change to file.php. Same change, but different commit.

*I need to bring these changesets back in sync*

To resolve this in mercurial, I would run the 3 commands below from Server 2.  Any merge conflicts would get resolved in an editor or meld.

```
hg pull -u ssh://remote-server1//shared-repository
hg merge
hg commit -m "Branch Merge"
```

How do you do this with git?

**What I've done**

Using https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts as a guide, I attempted `git pull` however it fails since I have not run `git config`.  This repository is in production and shared by many, so I'm trying to avoid setting an username.

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/17713604/456645, I ran this command:

```
git fetch ssh://remote-server1//shared-repository
```

It responds

```
From ssh://remote-server1//shared-repository
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
```

I have yet to figure out how to properly run `git reset` in this situation.

```
git reset ssh://remote-server1//shared-repository/master 
# FAILS (fatal: Invalid object name 'ssh'.)

git reset origin/master
# FAILS (fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.)

git reset FETCH_HEAD/master
# FAILS (fatal: ambiguous argument 'FETCH_HEAD/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.)
```

Looking further, I'm confused to only find a single branch

```
git branch -a
* master
```

Just to be sure it wasn't auto-merged, I check the history

```
git log -n 3 
# Here, I find the changesets that previously existed.  Nothing new
```

At this point, I don't even know what happens to the `git fetch`.  I see no evidence of the fetch.

Comment: List all branches with "git branch -a". Also, here is a git/mq cheat-sheet: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Git-hg-rosetta-stone/eb04a48a4830c1cb71fd04a56e8aaf8b4517329c

Comment: "origin" in the reset examples above is the name of one of the git remotes (Run git remote -v to list your remotes). You could add a remote to repo 1 with "git remote add server1 ssh://remote-server1//shared-repositor", and then you can use "git pull server1" / "git reset server1/mybranch" etc.

Comment: Updated response. `git branch -a` still shows only * master

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up comment as well.  That worked perfectly.  What's the `git reset server1/mybranch` for?  I haven't run that command yet.

Comment: @folkol Also, please feel free to make this an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Ultimately, I just set the user.email and user.name config settings and followed the instructions for adding remote servers to simplify the pull.

Comment: I added an answer, if the repositories are "bare repositories" (That is, you can not work in them), then you will have to clone repo2 out to your workstation and do it from there.

Comment: "git reset someremote/somebranch" will reset your current HEAD so that it points to "whatever someremote/somebranch" points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR version

Add a remote for the each repository.  I'll call the two repositories `alex` and `bob`, but you probably should choose more appropriate names.  Note that if you `git clone` one of them, that one will have the name `origin` automatically (although you can choose another name).  The below assumes you already have a related repository, and need to add both, but if you already have `origin` you just need to add the other one.

```
$ git remote add alex ssh://their.domain.name/their/path/to/repo.git
$ git remote add bob ssh://bobs.domain.name/and/his/path.git
```

After that you can easily `git fetch` everything (all branches, etc) from them:

```
$ git fetch alex
$ git fetch bob
```

You now have "remote tracking branches" named `alex/master`, `alex/develop`, etc., wherever Alex has branches named `master`, `develop`, etc.; and you have `bob/master` and so on wherever Bob has `master`.

Now if you wish to *merge* stuff, you can make your own local branch(es) corresponding to one of theirs:

```
$ git checkout -b alex-master alex/master
```

(`alex-master` is a local branch; you could just call it `master` if you prefer, but each local branch name must be unique, so you might have to move your own existing `master` out of the way first) and merge with `bob`'s:

```
$ git merge bob/master
```

(this merges `bob/master` into your local `alex-master`).  If you have permission you can push the result back to Alex's `master`:

```
$ git push alex alex-master:master
```

and also to Bob's `master`:

```
$ git push bob alex-master:master
```

The "refspec" given as the last argument to `git push` takes your local branch name on the left hand side of the colon, and their local branch name on the right.

Unlike Mercurial, there is no special branch name; `master` is just conventional, while in `hg`, `default` is a bit magic.  (Well, there's one special magic bit for `master` in git: it changes the way `git merge` spells the default commit message.  But that's really about it.)

---

There are a bunch of parts to this, some of which are mostly cosmetic/convenience, and some of which are crucial.

First, in git these days one mostly refers to repositories through "remotes".  A remote is partly a convenience construct but this also plays into the crucial bits, in terms of obtaining and retaining commits from another repository.

Mercurial has something much simpler than remotes, but which serves part of the convenience: in a `[paths]` section in your `.hgrc` file you can list the long URL under a short name:

```
[paths]
short = ssh://something.very.long/with/a/very/long/path/that/is/a/pain/to/type/every/time
```

or whatever.  Compare this to a git "remote", in `.git/config`:

```
[remote "short"]
    url = ssh://something.very.long/with/a/very/long/path/etc
```

So far these are exactly the same, just with different spellings/syntax.  But then there's this bit:

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/short/*
```

(in fact, this usually appears *before* the `url` but the order of these two does not matter).  We'll get back to this in a bit.

---

Next, the most direct equivalent of `hg pull` is indeed `git fetch`.  However, `hg pull` has `-u`, which `git fetch` most definitely does *not* do, because the internals of the two operations wind up being quite different because of the difference between a Mercurial branch and a git branch.

A Mercurial branch is sort of a "real thing", while a git branch is much more ephemeral.  More specifically / precisely, a git branch is much more like a Mercurial bookmark than it is like a Mercurial branch.  However, there's a concept (or maybe "conceit" might be a better word) that simply does not translate properly here: specifically, commits added to a Mercurial repository are numbered sequentially and remain in the repository even if nothing names them: you just wind up with an anonymous head.  For instance you can have a commit graph (shown with `hg log --graph` etc) that looks like:

```
o
|  o
o  |
|  o
o /
|/
o
```

There does not need to be any external name pointing to these two heads; they're just anonymous heads (within a branch since all commits in hg are within some branch by definition).

In git, by contrast, a commit with no external name is eligible to be garbage-collected (what `hg` might call "stripped", although the details differ).  So all of what hg calls "heads" *must* have some kind of name.  This is where a remote's `fetch =` line comes into effect.

"But wait," you might ask, "I can do `git fetch ssh://...` and that has no named remote!"  This is where that `HEAD -> FETCH_HEAD` bit comes in.

If you don't have a "remote", you can still bring in some branch (or even more than one) from another repository.  However, the heads of any branches thus obtained need a name.  This "name" is stuffed into the pseudo-branch named `FETCH_HEAD`.  The details get complicated, but if you bring over only a single branch, as in this case, it's easier to explain and think-about: essentially, git brings over the one named branch and, in your local repository, gives this the name `FETCH_HEAD`.

Note that a subsequent `git fetch` generally overwrites `FETCH_HEAD`, at which point all the commits you brought over are eligible for garbage-collection.  Thus, you need another step, once you have the commits.

---

Now, once you have some commits and want to retain them, there are different ways to do this.  The most `hg pull`-like is to use the "remote" mechanism.  Here, that `fetch =` line takes care of the problem.  When you `git fetch` from the remote, the remote has branch names pointing to all the branch heads (by definition since git *requires* this).  These branch names are references of the form `refs/heads/name`.

The `fetch =` line tells git how to *rename* the branches so that they have new, unique local names in your local repository.  By renaming `refs/heads/master` to `refs/remotes/short/master`, for instance, you get `short/master` as a new local name for what the remote called "branch `master`".  This retains the commits and we're good (though we still have to merge).

Alternatively, we can just get the one interesting branch over and call it `FETCH_HEAD` and then immediately merge.  When we do this, we pick some local branch (e.g., `master`), check it out if needed, and run `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Once the merge is done, we have our local branch (`master`, in this example) pointing, perhaps through a merge commit, to the commits we brought over via `git fetch`, so they are no longer vulnerable to a garbage-collection: they are on the branch, hence name-able via that branch name.  We can now safely overwrite `FETCH_HEAD` any time.

This last method—bringing stuff over but naming it `FETCH_HEAD`, then merging a local branch with `FETCH_HEAD`—is what the "git pull" command does.  In that sense, it's just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  I personally try to avoid the `pull` script as it has a lot of extra magic to handle various corner cases, which in the old days would go awry in some un-considered corner cases; and in general I prefer to fetch, look over what happened, and then choose whether and how to merge or rebase my own code.

---

Ultimately there's no single right way, but if you are going to do this more than once, I would add a git remote, and use the "remote branch" notion (the `fetch =` stuff that renames "their" branches to your own locally-stored "remote-tracking branches").

Comment: This was an eye opener! I really appreciate the comparisons with Mercurial terminology.  Also, the more subtle clarification clues ("check it out if needed") were a big help to understand the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Normally, a git remote is a "bare" repository, which means you can not have a checked out working copy on the server. This will work even if the server repo is a bare repo.

**[Clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)** one of the repositories to your local computer:

```
$ git clone ssh://remote-server1//shared-repository
```

cd into that folder:

```
$ cd shared-repository
```

**[Add](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote)** the second one as a **[remote](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)** with name server2:

```
$ git remote add server2 ssh://remote-server2//shared-repository
```

**[Fetch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)** and everything from the repository on server 2 (Same as nq pull):

```
$ git fetch server2
```

**[Merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)** the master branch of server2 into your local master:

```
$ git merge server2 master
```

**[Push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)** the result back to server 2:

```
$ git push server2 master
```

**[Push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)** the result back to server 1 (origin is the remote that you cloned from):

```
$ git push origin master
```