# What is the priority regarding git configuration?

Tags: git, git-config

If I set configuration on my `~/.gitconfig` file, which config would override it?

- project level config : `.git/config`
- system level config : `/etc/gitconfig`

Comment: What if you try first?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the Git manual (read http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES)

> If not set explicitly with --file, there are four files where git config will search for configuration options:
>
> **$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig**
>
> System-wide configuration file.
>
> **$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config**
>
> Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.
>
> **~/.gitconfig**
>
> User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.
>
> **$GIT_DIR/config**
>
> Repository specific configuration file.
>
> If no further options are given, all reading options will read all of these files that are available. If the global or the system-wide configuration file are not available they will be ignored. If the repository configuration file is not available or readable, git config will exit with a non-zero error code. However, in neither case will an error message be issued.
>
> The files are read in the order given above, with last value found taking precedence over values read earlier. When multiple values are taken then all values of a key from all files will be used.

Comment: what do you exactly mean in the last line with "When multiple values are taken then all values of a key from all files will be used." can you clarify it with an example?

Answer (score 74):

Lowest to highest priority:

- `/etc/gitconfig`: system wide, edited when `--system` parameter is used
- `~/.gitconfig`: user specific configuration, edited when `--global` parameter is used
- `.git/config`: repository specific configuration

Comment: where is the system wide file on a Windows system?

Comment: Google says `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig`, I'll have to take its word for it.

Comment: Yep. Thanks.  That is basically the location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig` .  I was really wondering about where that file was.

Comment: Thanks for digesting the manual and giving it to me in a monday morning format :)

Comment: In my configs, repository configs doesn't working for proxy. When I use git config http.proxy, git can't access server behind proxy. But when I use git config --global http.proxy it works. But I want repo specific proxy settings. Why it acting like this, what do you think?

Comment: @Erlan I think it's a global setting. You can try setting the HTTP_PROXY (or HTTPS_PROXY) environment variable before the pull to see if that helps.

Comment: I'm always confused about whether `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig` is used (that is to say, `<prefix>/etc/gitconfig/` or just `/etc/gitconfig`, for system.

Comment: @StevenLu For **macOS** is `/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig` , for **Linux** `/etc/gitconfig` and for  **Windows** is `<gitinstallation>/etc/gitconfig`