# "*** Please tell me who you are." when using SSH key

Tags: git, github

I'm using ssh key for git, after I added ssh key and check it authenticated successfully. But I still cannot commit code

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 2599

$ ssh-add ~/id_rsa
Identity added: /home/vagrant/id_rsa (/home/vagrant/id_rsa)

$ssh -T git@github.com
Hi my-git-username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But I cannot do commit

```
$ git commit -m "Develop Dockerfile for shopContainer"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.(none)')
```

Comment: This is covered earlier in [Setting up Git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#setting-up-git)

Answer (score 30):

> Run
>      git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>      git config --global user.name "Your Name"

**Note:** You are authenticated successfully but git needs your `username & email` to do a commit.

It is not related to authentication. Your `username/email` can be **different from your GitHub Account.**

You need to run the following commands for a **single time**.

```
$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com" 
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"

$ git config --list    # see if the 'name' & 'email' are set correctly
```

This `user.name` & `user.email` will be set globally in `~/.gitconfig` file.

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig     # see global config file
```

[**See more details**](https://github.com/sajibcse68/MyDailyLearn/blob/git/git/git-cheatsheet.md#configure-users-name-and-email)

Comment: But why is this info lost, and I need to type it again and again?

Comment: The point about cat ~/.gitconfig was the key...  had to edit that file

Answer (score 3):

This error tells you to omit the --global from the command nothing else.
 to get rid of this error follow my steps...

just put this command in your git console ->

```
    $ git config user.email "Your@emailaddres.com"
    $ git config user.name "Your name"
```

after this, your name and email will be set to the git and you are now ready to commit.

```
    $ git commit -m "Msg you want to print during commit"  ##This will commit successfully##
```

Output ->

```
    [master (root-commit) 7d5681a] done

    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

    create mode 100644 demo.txt
```

---

please let me know me if it is helpful to you guys.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestions from other answers no longer work in 2020. To remove the repeated entries, this is now the way to go:

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
git config --global --unset-all user.email
```

You might have to unset them locally as well, i.e. no --global flag. Then set them again as indicated in the other answers, i.e.:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type the same name that you have in your GitHub account.

GitHub account name:

[image: GitHub account name]

git user.name:

[image: git user.name]