# some error occured when commit My project to github

Tags: git, github

I am new to the github. I tryed to commit my project. but has occured following error on My cmd.

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Hema@Hema-PC.(none)')

how can solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: "please tell me who you are" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656761/git-please-tell-me-who-you-are-error)

Answer (score 0):

for this error you only have to execute the command they show

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

That will set your name in the ~/.gitconfig.

Comment: I need more explain actually I am very new to git

Comment: git config will edit your configuration
So for saving your commit git have to know who is it.
Theres command gonna only add the information to a main config file for git know who use him on this computer.
After that local will know who you are. 
You only have to add your files (git add file.txt) and commit (git commit -m "Message") before you can push it to github (git push)

Comment: @Hema The error quite explicitly explains what you need to do ;)