# Can't commit a new file

Tags: git

I am using Linux OS on Chromebook. I'm learning Java. I downloaded a repository from GitHub. It lacked of .gitignore file, so I created it and I'm trying to commit it, but I get a message

```
$ git commit -m "I've created .gitignore file"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <(null)>) not allowed
```

I've done that, I typed my GitHub email, and then my name and surname.

```
$ git config --global "my_GitHub_account_email@gmail.com" 
$ git config --global "Name Surname"
```

But when I type my name I get a message:

```
error: key does not contain a section: Name Surname
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual command you typed?

Comment: Can you have a look at your .gitconfig and see if it is correctly formed?

Comment: $ cat .gitignore 
/bin/
.idea/*
.classpath*
.project*
*.iml

Comment: I've never used Linux system before, whatever I do is  from what I've googled. I followed all steps from my course video. I also tried to create a text file, abc.txt. And it still brings the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: "please tell me who you are" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656761/git-please-tell-me-who-you-are-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+tell+me+who+you+are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed

```
$ git config --global "my_GitHub_account_email@gmail.com" 
$ git config --global "Name Surname"
```

You forget **`user.name`** and **`user.email`**.

The commands you have to type are:

```
$ git config --global user.email "my_GitHub_account_email@gmail.com" 
$ git config --global user.name "Name Surname"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the `git config --global user.name "Your Name"` without double apex ", like this:

```
git config --global user.name my name and username
```

run like this

```
git config --global user.name "my name and username"
```