# when i write git commit -m "Complete chapter 1" it is not working

Tags: git, git-bash, git-commit

```
cd Desktop
mkdir Story
cd Story
touch chapter1.txt
atom .
git init
git add chapter1.txt
git status
git commit -m "complete chapter 1"
```

It show me this error message:

***Please tell me who you are.

Run

```
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

to set your account's default identity.

Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got
>   'Hi@DESKTOP-EL5QS59.(none)')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: "please tell me who you are" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656761/git-please-tell-me-who-you-are-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Please+tell+me+who+you+are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git` needs to know the info of the user who's committing the changes. This message shows that you have not configured your details in git.

As @Amadan mentioned, it is telling you everything in the error. You just need to run the following two commands:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Replace `your@example.com` with your email and `Your Name` with your name and run these commands. You will be able to commit the changes.

For more details you can visit the guides by GitHub:

- [Setting your commit email in git](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git)
- [Setting your username in git](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-username-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following commands for a single time.

```
 git config --global user.email "you@example.com" 
 git config --global user.name "Your Name"

 git config --list    # see if the 'name' & 'email' are set correctly
```

Comment: Thanks all of you for your valuable time. Now the command is working according to your direction.

Comment: This is copy of above answer by @Saqib